# One storyboard not seeing localization .strings while the other one localizes perfectly

Tags: ios, ios8, localization, xcode6, xcode6.3

I have two storyboards in my app, and I'm trying to add Turkish language option to both using localizable strings. My main storyboard maps just fine; when I change simulator language to Turkish, it loads the Turkish strings and displays them perfectly. However, my other storyboard still displays in English. I've got everything exactly the same, but one just doesn't work. I've tried deleting the app from simulator and rebuilding, but no avail. Here is how they are set up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In addition, they both have auto layout enabled, size classes disabled, and they both have my app checked at Target Membership. Everything about them is the same. Why is one localizing but the other doesn't?

Comment: Just to take the simulator out of the equation as it has been flaky with respect to localization in recent versions of Xcode, do you observe same behavior on a device?

Comment: @MichaelTeper On my device, it doesn't localize at all! Everything is in English even when I switch my device to Turkish and delete/rebuild the app. Even some English strings are missing now. Why can this be?

Comment: I don't use Base file, I just use english and my custom language (spanish in my case). Select English and deselect Base.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu it's a bit hard to tell. You might want to take this a level deeper and compare references to these files and their localizations inside the .pbxproj file (r-click your .xcodeproj file and select Show Package Contents menu item).

Comment: @MichaelTeper I've ended up resetting to the last commit with git, and starting over by not using a base file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the localization files (after copying to somewhere safe), removed all localization related stuff from the project, and started over. It worked.